# Auto-generating element annotations in xsd file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xsd, dataset

I'm working on a tool to automatically update our typed datasets when our xsd schema files change. I've noticed that when I add an xsd file to Visual Studio and open it up in the design view, if I change a property and save there are substantial changes to the xsd file. Basically a lot of annotations are added to each element. For example:

```
<xs:element name="EventWeather">
```

becomes the following:

```
<xs:element name="EventWeather" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="EventWeatherDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableEventWeather" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="EventWeatherRowChanged" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="EventWeather" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="EventWeatherRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="EventWeatherRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="EventWeatherRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="EventWeatherRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="EventWeatherRow" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="EventWeather" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="EventWeatherRowChangeEvent">
```

The problem is that if these annotations are not added to the xsd file, the resulting typed dataset code generated by xsd.exe does not compile and gives me an error saying that the dataset already contains a definition for one of the generated types. I would like to be able to automatically add these annotations to the xsd file without having to open it in Visual Studio but have not been able to find any information about that.

Does anyone know how I can leverage this xsd updating functionality from visual studio using the command line? My xsd files are very large so adding these by hand is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VisualStudio will rewrite XSD, WSDL, or any XML file as it sees fit. A lot of it is to tell the design view how to display the data. Those extra things are just extra data for VS to do it's magic with.

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I want to do is get visual studio to rewrite the xsd on command without my having to open/close the document in the IDE manually.